# Alamofire CRUD POST a JSON

Tags: json, swift, serialization, alamofire

How can I do POST Parameters in JSON format to an Alamofire Request using the CRUD [example](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#crud--authorization) as Base? I am unable to send my Parameters.

Below is my router generator:

```
fileprivate enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {

case login(reqData: Data)
case preferencesIndex()
case preferencesUpdate(parameters: Parameters)

static let baseURLString = "http://test.com"

var method: HTTPMethod {
    switch self {
    case .login, .preferencesIndex:
        return .get
    case .preferencesUpdate:
        return .post
    }
}

var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .login:
        return "/login"
    case .preferencesIndex:
        return "/preferences/list"
    case .preferencesUpdate:
        return "/preferences/update"
    }
}

// MARK: URLRequestConvertible
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let url = try Router.baseURLString.asURL()
    let paramsDefault: Parameters = ["_format" : "json", "_authorization" : "testkey"]

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: paramsDefault)

    switch self {
    case .preferencesUpdate(let parameters):
        //POST JSON
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        urlRequest.httpBody = data
        urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    default:
        break
    }

    return urlRequest
}

}
```

The error I receive is as follows:

> Request failed with error: JSON could not be serialized because of error:
>   The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

I think my problem is at serialization, because I send parameters as `Parameters` type...

Comment: Are you using swift 3?

Comment: Yes, I use swift 3

Comment: I want :

1) generate url

ex: http://test.com/preferences/update?_format=json&_authorization=testkey

-base url: http://test.com
-path: /preferences/update
-query string: _format, authorization

2) send JSON:

 ["data" : ["items" :  [["name": "items_ids", "value": "1,2,3"]]]]

But I can't make this in my router generator..

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine part of the problem might be that you're trying to URL encode the request when you want to JSON encode the request. You have this line:

```
urlRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: paramsDefault)
```

But you want this:

```
urlRequest = try JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, with: paramsDefault)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have other problem now.. paramsDefault must be added in url as query string (like that: "?_format=json&authorization=testkey") and parameters must be passed as JSON in httpBody.. but because method type is .post I can't add paramsDefault as query string. I hope you understand what I mean :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to send request like below in swift 3

```
let urlString = "https://httpbin.org/get"
let headers = ["Authorization": "123456"]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["foo": "bar"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
   print(response.result.value)
}
```